# Changing element height depending on a selection of combobox

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a combobox for selecting media types. I would like mediaelement's height to change when .vmw, .mpeg or .avi files are selected. How can I achieve this with MVVM approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you perhaps want to change the height when MediaElement opens a different Source?

Comment: Yes, but this source is chosen from the combobox

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the `Width` and `Height` of the MediaElement directly to its `Source` property with an appropriate converter, which selects the proper size depending on the media type:

```
<MediaElement
    Width="{Binding Path=Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MediaElementSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Width}"
    Height="{Binding Path=Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MediaElementSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Height}"/>
```

The converter:

```
public class MediaElementSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const double defaultWidth = 320d;
    private const double defaultHeight = 240d;
    private const double wmvWidth = 640d;
    private const double wmvHeight = 480d;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Uri source = value as Uri;

        if (source != null)
        {
            if (source.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".wmv"))
            {
                return (parameter as string) == "Width" ? wmvWidth : wmvHeight;
            }

            // more media types ...
        }

        return (parameter as string) == "Width" ? defaultWidth : defaultHeight;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks indeed, it seems quite useful. I will try

Comment: As I applied the solution you provided, I want to ask a question. The converter works but the source is always null. Could you help figuring this out? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you set the source? I assume it's bound to the SelectedItem of the ComboBox.

Comment: As I applied the solution you provided, I want to ask a question. The converter works only when the first time I debug the application. Then it never does as I change the file. Could you help figuring this out? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you "change the file"? Is the `Source` property of the MediaElement bound to the `SelectedItem` property of the ComboBox, and does the ComboBox contain file names or URIs? I just tried exactly that and it worked.

Comment: It wasn't exactly like that so I must try enhancing it. It should work, yes. Thanks a lot. I can see it clearer now

Comment: The important thing is that the `Source` property changes, whether by a binding or from code behind doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to bind the `ComboBox` to a list of self created `MediaTypeDefinition` classes.

```
public class MediaTypeDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

You can then bind the `SelectedItem` to the height of the media element.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="mediaTypeList" ItemsSource="{Binding Definitions}" SelectedValuePath="Name" />

<MediaElement Height="{Binding SelectedItem.Height, Elementname=mediaTypeList}" />
```